# .NetCore gRPC client is not able to call Node with NestJs gRPC Server

Tags: node.js, .net-core, grpc, nest

We have a gRPC server in NodeJs with Nest running on separate port 3001, and when we call this from the Node client it works fine. But one of our microservice is in.NETCore when we try to call it gives us the below error. Currently, we are stuck at the 3,4 point. if someone can guide us it will be very helpful.

```
1. Status(StatusCode="Unimplemented", Detail="The server does not implement the method", ResponseCode: "404")
2. Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Bad gRPC response. Response protocol downgraded to HTTP/1.1.")
3. An error occurred while sending the request. Http2ConnectionException: The HTTP/2 server sent invalid data on the connection.    HTTP/2 error code 'PROTOCOL_ERROR' (0x1).
4. An error occurred while sending the request. IOException: The request was aborted. Http2ConnectionException: The HTTP/2 server sent invalid data on the connection. HTTP/2 error code 'PROTOCOL_ERROR' (0x1).
```

What we have tried,

1. `AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);`
2. On startup we use the Kestrel with listening to Http1,

   `options.ListenLocalhost(5000, o => o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1);`
3. Added HttpClientHandler configuration for certificate and SslProtocols

Comment: From your question it's unclear whether you're using a .NET client or a node client (and whether you're using grpc-web or standard grpc). But from the logs, the most obvious thing to try is to switch the server to `o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2` (you need Http2 for gRPC). AFAICT It seems that the client is trying to connect with http2 and the connections are being downgraded to http1. You need to make sure that both your client and server are using http/2.